# Cygwin Compile .c into .so

Tags: compilation

I'm trying to compile a .c file into .so using Cygwin on Windows 7.

I installed Cygwin following this guide...How to Compile Linux Programs Under Windows with Cygwin:

http://www.maketecheasier.com/compile-linux-programs-under-windows/

I installed library packages: gcc-core, gcc-g++, make and wget.

I did: cd C:/cygwin/x and found the directory with My .c file.  The .c file is named: myproxocket.c

My instructions for compiling the source code:
  gcc -o myproxocket.so myproxocket.c -shared -ldl

I get: -bash: gcc: command not found

Can someone familiar with Cygwin help Me compile .c into .so?

Do I have to make a .o file and then make a .so file?

Comment: As the error says, it's not finding gcc in your PATH.  Find out where it installed gcc.exe and check your PATH (`echo $PATH`)to see what's missing.

Comment: Thanks! pak.  I had a friend compile it for Me...